# css class override with style html snippet

Tags: html, css

Hi I am using a CMS (content management system) that uses CSS to color the buttons and menu items.

I used Firefox developer to inspect the element and the button is labeled

```
<span class="cta-button cta-icon-left  cta-custom-color-0 cta-button-medium cta-button-nomocaption cta-button-nomosubcaption cta-button-nomoicon">
```

I believe 'cta-custom-color-0' is where the color is contained for the button.

I tried adding the following HTML snippet to the page

```
<style>
.cta-custom-color-0 {background-color: #8640a8;}
</style>
```

However it isn't changing the button color.

What is the correct CSS syntax to override the color with a style snippet?

see [Send to Google Maps Button here on sample page](http://earthgrid.com/expomobile/map.html)

Comment: You may need more specificity.  Does `span.cta-custom-color-0` make any difference?

Comment: Most browser's dev tools will show how style is being applied to an element  which is the easiest way to determine the issue. In the default firefox inspector it's under the 'rules' tab which lives on the right-hand side of the panel.

Comment: span.cta-button.cta-icon-left.cta-custom-color-0.cta-button-medium.cta-button-nomocaption.cta-button-nomosubcaption.cta-button-nomoicon

Comment: yeah, or press F12 in google chrome and check the elements style

Comment: Span. didn't make a difference. and I did have a </style> on my snippet. I put a link to the page we're working on above 'Send to Google Maps Button' on sample page is the one we're trying to color purple.

Comment: add you style as attribute into span tag to override any other styling `<span class="cta-button cta-icon-left  cta-custom-color-0 cta-button-medium cta-button-nomocaption cta-button-nomosubcaption cta-button-nomoicon" style="background-color: #8640a8;">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like commenters have said you need to use you browser's developer tools, and find the element of interest.

Turns out you are trying to set the color of a wrapper, but the actual black color comes from an inner element with class `.cta-body.cta-normal`

So I believe you would need:

```
.cta-body.cta-normal {background-color: #8640a8;}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show how to change the 'hover' button color as well? right now its grey. Thanks!

Comment: Look in the inspector, you should find a button (top right in my screenshot – Chrome) that says `:hov`. That will help you find the corresponding rule

Answer (score 0):

```
.cta-custom-color-0.cta-custom-color-0 {}
```

You can keep chaining these until it has enough **specificity** to work. I would avoid other hacks or adding lots of parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
span.cta-custom-color-0 .cta-body.cta-normal {background-color: #8640a8!important;}
span.cta-custom-color-0 .cta-body.cta-over {background-color: #00d486!important;}
</style>
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed. Here is the final snippet. Adding 'span' and also adding !important as above clarified it.

The biggest help was from tmslnz - thank you!!!~ with the insight and images above to show that .cta-body.cta-normal - it was a 'nested' CSS.

Once again thank you to all who contributed. I trust this will help many developers who are working with fixed CMS systems to modify their color schemes.  - Viktor

Answer (score -2):

.cta-custom-color-0 {background-color: #8640a8!important;}

Before adding this make sure this class is not used anywhere else otherwise it will add this color on all the element which have class 'cta-custom-color-0'

Comment: `!important` should only be used to override third-party style attributes, if ever.